# How do I make this VBA faster, Removes Blank Cells

Tags: vba, excel, nonblank

This VBA array works and removes all the blanks I want. But it's extending all the way down to like the millonth row, taking up valuable computer resources. I need to either make the VBA stop if "the next 10 rows in the array are not filled with data" OR I just need it to stop at row 2000. It scans I1:K2000 & the data is displayed in M1:O2000.

```
Function NonBlanks(DataRange As Variant) As Variant

Dim i As Long, J As Long, NumRows As Long, NumCols As Long, RtnA() As Variant
Dim RtnRow As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0
If TypeName(DataRange) = "Range" Then DataRange = DataRange.Value2

NumRows = UBound(DataRange)
NumCols = UBound(DataRange, 2)

ReDim RtnA(1 To NumRows, 1 To NumCols)

For i = 1 To NumRows
If DataRange(i, 1) <> "" Then
RtnRow = RtnRow + 1
For J = 1 To NumCols
If DataRange(i, J) <> "" Then RtnA(RtnRow, J) = DataRange(i, J) _
Else RtnA(RtnRow, J) = ""
Next J
  End If
Next i

For i = RtnRow + 1 To NumRows
For J = 1 To NumCols
RtnA(i, J) = ""
Next J
Next i

NonBlanks = RtnA
Application.ScreenUpdating = 1
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling the function?  It sounds like the Range you're passing isn't bounded by the used cells.

Comment: I added an answer which will help the situation, but the larger question here is: what is the end goal of all this?  There are much easier ways to find blank cells: `DataRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)` will give them all to you.  There are probably faster ways to this also even if the blanks are just a step in the process.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `DataRange` is a valid `Range` object, you can do a very quick limit on the size of the range with

```
Set DataRange = Intersect(DataRange.Parent.UsedRange, DataRange)
```

Stick that at the top before you do the `If TypeName...` bit.

The `Parent` of a `Range` is a `Worksheet` object.  The `Worksheet` maintains a property called `UsedRange` which includes all cells that have data or formatting or are somehow different than a default blank cell.  It beats going corner to corner on the whole sheet.

Comment: Ahh ok, I get it. It didn't work, but I think I'm using it wrong. When I enter the array into the cells "=nonblanks(I:K)" it will extend all the way to the millionth cell making the file massive; I understand I'm using the entire columns but there's no data past 2000. I just wanted to extend far enough so when there is more data in I:K the array will already be there. Now the workaround I did before your answer is just "=nonblanks(I1:K2000). I just had the problem of it going to the millionth cell...